# Alpha style bibliography: List of citations in the alphabetical order

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, citing, cite-package

```
\bibliographystyle{alpha}
\bibliography{myBibFile}
```

References page of the pdf file is well organized, but when I have a citation list like `\cite{ref1, ref2}`, in the pdf file, for exemple, I have [BSDR+09, Age11].

The question is: **In alpha style bibliography**, how the list of citations can be in the alphabetical order? I.e, [Age11, BSDR+09].

Comment: If you are using `bibtex` why do you tag your question with `biblatex`? Second, are you using `natbib`package? and third, could you bring us a full MWE of your problem?

Comment: @Aradnix: 1) I'm not using natbib. 2) What does MWE stand for? 3) Can you please suggest the right tags? I will then edit them.

Comment: 1. Take a look at the tags you're using. You _must_ use only those related with the question for avoid confusion and improve future searchings. 2. a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) is a piece of code that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, a **full** MWE starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: 3. You can simple tag your question as you do but removing `biblatex` (at least you use it) and changing it for `bibtex`, and if you are not using `natbib`then erae that tag.